# elementaryOS won't start Xorg

Tags: release-loki, boot

So one night I forgot to plug in my laptop with elementaryOS, I closed the lid, and the battery died. After I charged it again, I turned on my laptop and the only thing that I got was a blinking cursor. After finding some help on forums, I figured out how to go to the terminal. Now, when I try to use startx, it just won't start the desktop. It will output about how messages are outputed, the screen would go black, and then It will end the task. I tried various methods, such as upgrading the kernel and reinstaling Xorg, but none of them worked. So, someone knows how to fix it? Here are the specs:

HP Pavilion 14-v005la

AMD A8-6410

4 GB of RAM

500 GB HDD

Answer (score 0):

Remove these directories

```
rm .Xauthority .ICEauthority
```

And clear cache

```
rm -Rf .cache
```

These commands helped me, it might solve your problem

Comment: I decided to install Deepin finally, but I will try to see if that solution works on a VM.